# vs code show black blank screen

Tags: visual-studio-code

when i open vs code, vs code open with blank screen

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2t8Y6.png)

vs code is not run my laptop so please help me in that case.

Comment: see: [Visual Studio Code starts as a blank window, and stays that way](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/114459)

Comment: Possibly related: [VS Code Blank Screen on Opening](/q/69364381/), [Black or blank screen coming after visual studio code update](/q/72899294), [VSCode blank screen on 1.19.0 update](/q/47866729)